# file_get_contents();

Tags: php

У нас на сервере висит парсер, и парсит он вот так:

```
file_get_contents('http://ls.4geo.ru/pulse');
```

И все работало хорошо до сегодняшнего дня, теперь ни с того ни с сего она по выполнению этой команды начал выдавать:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Причем не могу получить ни один адрес через эту функцию, где чего сломалось не пойму(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего какие-то проблемы:

1. DNS - имя ls.4geo.ru не преобразуется в IP адрес. Проверить можно через `$server_ip = gethostbyname("ls.4geo.ru"); print_r($server_ip)`
2. Что-то с самим PHP (может обновляли) либо сочетание PHP + OS. cм. [bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=php_network_getaddresses](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=php_network_getaddresses&boolean=0&limit=10&order_by=&direction=ASC&cmd=display&status=All&php_os=&phpver=&assign=&author_email=&bug_age=0)

Comment: Поставил Gnome на Debian и DNS потерлись, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно хостер запретил использовать функцию `file_get_contents` для удаленного контента,